# Correlation of GLM coefficent when Y is correlated

Tags: regression, correlation, generalized-linear-model, covariance

First to motivate the problem, let me start with a solved example. Say I have some fixed design matrix $X$ and random vectors $Y_1, Y_2, \dots, Y_N$ which have a normal distribution. I can get the vector of regression coefficient estimators $[\hat{a}_1, \hat{\beta_1}, \hat{\boldsymbol{C}}_1], [\hat{a_2}, \hat{\beta_2}, \hat{\boldsymbol{C}}_2], \dots, [\hat{a}_N, \hat{\beta_N}, \hat{\boldsymbol{C}}_N]$ using $(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY_i$ for $i = 1, 2, \dots, N$. Here, $\hat{a}_i$ is the intercept, $\hat{\beta}_i$ is the regression coefficient, and $\hat{\boldsymbol{C}_i}$ is the vector of covariate coefficients. It is known that the covariance of any pair of $\hat{\beta}_i$ and $\hat{\beta}_j$ is a function of the covariance of the corresponding $Y_i$ and $Y_j$.

Let $H = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and $H_1$ be $H$ with the rows corresponding to $a$ and $\boldsymbol{C}$ removed. i.e. $H_1$ is a row of the hat matrix corresponding to $\beta$.

$Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_j}) = Cov(H_1Y_i,H_1Y_j) = H_1Cov(Y_i,Y_j)IH_1$

My question is can I express the covariance of the coefficients of GLMs as some function of the covariance of $Y$? i.e. $Y$ follows some distribution in the exponential family other than Gaussian and $E(g(P(Y|X))) = X\beta$ where $g$ is the canonical link function. Then can $Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_j})$ be expressed as some function of the covariance of $Y$ such that $Cov(\hat{\beta_i}, \hat{\beta_j}) = f(Cov(Y_i,Y_j),X)$. $\hat{\beta}$ can't be expressed analytically as function of $Y$ which makes it less obvious.

Comment: Your notation doesn't seem to work out, because your "$\hat\beta_i$" must be coefficient *vectors* for the $N$ separate regressions.  Moreover, once the "intercept and covariate rows" are removed from $H,$ what could possibly be left?  Regardless, there is no hope of such a simple formula for covariances in other GLMs, especially any one that uses a nonlinear link function, so the very meaning of "extended to" needs clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have clarified my notation and question. My end goal is to be able to say something about estimating the correlation of the betas from y for GLMs. In simulation, I can show the sample covariance matrices of betas and Y (transformed to uniform and then Gaussian via CDF, i.e. correlation computed on this transformed quantity) are close under the null. I'm wondering maybe we could say something (i.e. very informal, direction for a proof) about the Gaussian copula for Y and beta.

Comment: That's usually done with the Fisher Information matrix, since GLMs are usually fit using Maximum Likelihood.

Comment: Can you perhaps give me a general direction for how that would be useful here? I can see the use if wanted to compute the the covariance between say, wald statistics computed from beta hat / se(beta hat) with se(beta hat) computed from fisher information. Not sure how that is relevant for just beta hat.

Comment: The Fisher Information matrix determines the full variance-covariance matrix of the estimates.  The SE's are from the diagonal entries only.

Comment: I'll look into that. Thanks!